# Bessel Functions Integral Representation proof

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

So, I'm still working with Bessel functions and trying to proof the following identity, but I'm at a loss for what could possibly be going on here:

[image]

Any idea how to even approach the proof for something like this?  I know that there is a fourier series representation for the cosine/sine terms on the left, but that series doesn't seem to lead to anything useful.  I ahve also looked into trying to express J as a contour integral in the complex domain, but I can't seem to get anywhere witht hat approach.  If you guys have any insight regarding where to start for this proof or any additional resources, I'd greatly appreciate it; this has me stumped.

Answer (score 0):

The integral is equal to

$$\frac12 \Re{\left [ \int_0^{2 \pi} d\theta \, e^{i (-i \alpha \cos{\theta} + \beta \sin{\theta})} \right ]}$$

Then use the fact that

$$-i \alpha \cos{\theta} + \beta \sin{\theta}  = \sqrt{\beta^2+(-i \alpha)^2} \cos{\left (\theta  +i \operatorname{arctanh}{(\beta/\alpha)}\right)}$$

To show that the integral does not depend on the imaginary phase term, consider the integral

$$\oint_R dz \, e^{i \sqrt{\beta^2-\alpha^2} \cos{z}}$$

where $R$ is the rectangle having vertices $0$, $2 \pi$, $i \operatorname{arctanh}{(\beta/\alpha)}$, and $2 \pi + i \operatorname{arctanh}{(\beta/\alpha)}$.  Because the integrand is analytic inside $R$, the contour integral is zero by Cauchy's Theorem.  In addition, the integrals along the vertical paths cancel because $\cos{z}=\cos{(z+2 \pi)}$ for any complex $z$.  Therefore

$$\int_0^{2 \pi} d\theta \, e^{i \sqrt{\beta^2-\alpha^2} \cos{\left (\theta  +i \operatorname{arctanh}{(\beta/\alpha)}\right)}} = \int_0^{2 \pi} d\theta \, e^{i \sqrt{\beta^2-\alpha^2} \cos{\theta}}$$

The result follows from the well-known integral representation of $J_0$.

Comment: Hmmmmm, so contour integration was the way to go after all.  I'm not particularly sure I understand this arctanh(beta/alpha) portion.  Where is that coming from, and why can you neglect it in the integration?

Comment: @Incognito: It's the complex version of a standard trick used to express a weighted sum of cosine and sine in in terms of a cosine of something plus a phase.  The phase is imaginary and turns out to be the tanh term.  You can neglect the imaginary phase for exactly the reason I posted, because of Cauchy's theorem on the contour integral I wrote.  BTW contour integration is merely used to prove we can neglect the imaginary phase; it is not used so much in evaluating the actual integral.  For that, I rely on the well-known representation of $J_0$.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I really don't understand how the arctanh may be introduced, nor how it may be neglected.  I see how the vertical components cancel, but how does that allow us to neglect a whole part in the entire contour integral?

Comment: $$\arctan{i y} = i \operatorname{arctanh}{y}$$  If you see how the vertical portions cancel, then as the contour is a rectangle, it does reason that the integrals along the horizontal portions also must cancel, and therefore...

Comment: Alright, I guess that's a bit clearer, but I'm still trying to understand where that comes from.  Personally, I would express that relation as:
$$-i\alpha\cos{\theta}+\beta\sin{\theta}=\sqrt{\beta^2+(-i\alpha)^2}*e^{i\theta}$$
Where is this cosine coming from, and why do we need to itnroduce a phase here?...

Comment: @Incognito: and you'd be wrong.  Look, the exercise requires some careful handling of imaginary quantities.  Work through the steps I provided in detail, especially the conversion to the cosine plus phase.  Use the exponential definitions of the cosine and sine to understand the imaginary arguments.

Comment: http://www.ling.upenn.edu/courses/cogs501/TowardsTheDFT.html Under section "Basic formulae for sinusoids".  This is the closest resource I've found for explaining this identity, but it's expressed in terms of a sine - as opposed to a cosine.